# How to refresh ALL cell through VBA

Tags: vba

Is there anyway to trigger (from VBA) excel asking it to reevaluate ALL its excel cells ?

thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [calculate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223802%28office.11%29.aspx) method can recalculate individual worksheets or the entire workbook.

Edit re comment:
Try setting Application.Volatile (true) before calling calculate.

Comment: I tried this method. At the Initial call it will revaluate the sheet, but in subsequent calls it does not revaluate all cells. Is there any condition need to be satifies on order to reevaluate cells by Calculate function?

Answer (score 2):

Application.Volatile is a vba interpreter trick that only works when the call is placed directly after the method definition, after that Application.Calculate should reevaluate the function as well

```
Public Function FooMethod()
Application.Volatile true
```

as the help states ...

> Marks a user-defined function as volatile. A volatile function must be recalculated whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the worksheet. A nonvolatile function is recalculated only when the input variables change. This method has no effect if it's not inside a user-defined function used to calculate a worksheet cell

Answer (score 0):

If you use the SendKeys method, you can use Shift+F9 to do this.