# How to refresh cells using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I've attempted various solutions from Stack Overflow ([How to refresh ALL cell through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370930/how-to-refresh-all-cell-through-vba), [Getting Excel to refresh data on sheet from within VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154434/how-do-you-get-excel-to-refresh-data-on-sheet-from-within-vba)) to refresh cells in Excel VBA without success in Excel 2010.

These methods include toggling the calculation state of the active sheet (`ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False` followed by `ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True`), and using `Application.Calculate` and `Application.CalculateFull`.

Unfortunately, none have worked. Interestingly, manually refreshing a cell via right-click works fine. However, trying to programmatically refresh a cell with `Sheets("Name_of_sheet").Range("D424").Refresh` triggers exception 438.

**Questions:**

1. How can I adapt the VBA script to work across Excel 2003, 2007, and 2010?
2. How can I programmatically select a source file for refreshing data?

**Edit:**

- My main goal is to replicate the manual process of right-clicking a cell in "worksheet 3" to refresh it, specifically automating the selection of a .txt file as the source.
- The Excel file I'm working with was created a decade ago. In Excel 2010, manual cell refresh works by right-clicking and choosing a .txt file. I'm looking to automate this in VBA.

Comment: how are you loading the spreadsheet and also are you trying to refresh a s/s from code in another s/s? Please give more detail

Comment: Dumb Question but are Macros Enabled?

Comment: if you are enabling calculations at the application level but opening a spreadsheet from the original then you might be calculating the wrong workbook.

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes it is :)

Comment: You need to show us your code.  All of the methods that you list ***DO*** work, so you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I work on excel file which created 10 years ago. When opening it in excel 2010, I can go to a cell and right click on it and choose refresh and then choose the .txt file to refresh from, and it works just fine. Now when I try to do it automatically within VBA all the code above doesn't help. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using **[`Application.Calculation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821260%28v=office.14%29.aspx)**

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: doesn't work as well... maybe it is because my second question. How can I choose using VBA the source file to refresh from?

Comment: @0x90 You can try `Application.Calculate`. I don't quite understand your second question.

Comment: How the cells now where to take the data from? so it will know what to put in it?

Comment: Could you post the other parts of the code, or explain your workflow?

Answer (score 3):

For an individual cell you can  use:

`Range("D13").Calculate`

OR

```
Cells(13, "D").Calculate
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I finally used mouse events and keystrokes to do it:

```
Sheets("worksheet34").Select
Range("D15").Select
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
SetCursorPos 200, 600 'set mouse position at 200, 600
Call mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0) 'click left mouse
Application.SendKeys ("R")
```

Comment: i had this problem today, and tried all of the other answers on this page. then i saw this, and it reminded me that i can just record macros in excel. man...excel is a PITA.

Comment: @sion_corn that is indeed an option to record a macro... :)

Answer (score 1):

just a reminder;

be careful when using

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

this sets the entire excel application to calculate formula's either automatically or manually. If you use

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

you'll notice your automatic formulas no longer work.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can force excel to recalculate a cell or range of cells by marking the cell/range as dirty.

Example :

```vb
' Recalculate Column D4 to D24
Sheets("Name_of_sheet").Range("D4:D24").Dirty
```

or

```vb
' Recalculate Cell D4<br>
Sheets("Name_of_sheet").Range("D4").Dirty<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Calculate` didn't work for my function.  Not even when followed by `DoEvents`.

What I found that works is to **re-enter** the formula in the cell.
A simple way to get the formula is to start recording a `macro`, use `F2` to edit the cell, then press `enter`.  The macro will make a great copy of the function text with all needed quotes.

Below is an example.

```
Sheets("Name_of_sheet").Range("D424").FormulaR1C1 = "=now()"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cells(x, y).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Selection.Value
```

works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

I have a long "macro" in a workbook > 20 MB, tens of thousands of lines, that calls a dll written in Fortran. None of these methods worked:

```
Call Application.Calculate
Call Application.CalculateFull
Call Application.CalculateFullRebuild
Re-entering the formula
Range.Dirty

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
```

This worked:

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.SendKeys "{F2}{Enter}{NumLock}"  'SendKeys turns off NumLock for some reason
On Error GoTo 0
```

This even worked when a chart was selected.